# Python: mandatory newline after if statement in console?

Tags: python

maybe I'm missing something very simple ? However I can't see the reason why if I paste the following code in a python shell :

```
a = 0
if True:
    a += 1
a += 2
```

I get this error:

> ```
> a += 2
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

However if I put a newline before the a += 2 line, the statement works.

Same behaviour in both Python 2 and 3, but here is no error if I launch the code from a file.

Is there some python rule I'm missing ?

Comment: Yes the original `python` REPL requires a new line after each indented block, while the `ipython` REPL does not.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea. So it's actually a bug / feature / limitation of the REPL rather than python syntax.

Comment: This is actually due to the fact that the original REPL does not require additional libraries to work (for example it does not use `GNU readline`) while other REPL contains additional libraries to support that "simple" feature (`ipython` runs with `prompt_toolkit`, a pure python replacement for `readline`). This is not a bug nor a feature, I think it is simply the result of the decision of limiting the number of dependencies for the compilation  of the python interpreter.