# Python SyntaxError: invalid syntax for a valid statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

I have created a MWE:

```py
x = True
if x:
    print('111111')
y = 1
```

When running in python interactive mode, I get

```
>>> x = True
>>> if x:
...     print('111111')
... y = 1
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    y = 1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

The code looks very correct. If I add them line by line, they will  be fine but now when copying them all together.

What is wrong?

Comment: In Python's interactive mode, you have to end all multi-line statements (such as the one starting `if x:`) with a blank line, before you enter another top-level statement.

Comment: dupe of dupe of ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/46805254/674039

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpreter is saying that the indentation of the second statement y=1 was unexpected.You should have entered a blank line to end the first statement (i.e., "if") , before you start writing the next statements(i.e y=1).

```
>>> x=True
>>> if x:
...     print('1111')
...
1111
>>> y=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put a space after the final line of an indented block in Python terminal, to indicate the end of the indentation.

So just hit enter again before writing y = 1.

Answer (score 0):

you have to enter a new line after the print statement two times. Then only  it exits the if statement